# Notification count in Android Nougat (SDK 24)

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, deprecated, android-7.0-nougat

Is there any replacement for **Notification.number** field that was deprecated with Android **API 24**?

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#number) says:

> This field was deprecated in API level 24.
>   this number is not shown anymore

Looks like Notification.EXTRA_INFO_TEXT also gives null.
Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: Use a custom view, I guess.

Comment: Hi, its also observed in Nexus6 also, badge count is not appearing even though setNumber API is used! Any idea why??

Answer (score 0):

It is now *un*deprecated in API 26, and is now shown as a badge on certain launchers. How very strange.

For API 24-25, I think you were expected to stack multiple notifications in a group. Which doesn't work if you want the number to be eg '100 new emails' - you aren't going to post 100 notifications. It's good they have re-thought this.

edit: API 26 badge documentation: https://developer.android.com/preview/features/notification-badges.html